# Laravel - join comments ,posts, users

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to return every posts with each one's author, and also every post's comments with it's author.
this is what i did:

**The controller:**

`$posts = Post::with('comments', 'user')->latest()->paginate(3);`

**The Post model:**

```
public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

**The Comment model:**

```
public function users() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\User');
}
```

This returns every post with their authors and the comments but not the comment's author.
what else should i do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **Comment** model:

```
public function users() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\User');
}
```

Implies that a user entry in database would have a `comment_id` field. But instead it should really have a `user_id` field in the `comments` database table:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Now you can eager load authors of comments as well:

```
$posts = Post::with('comments.user', 'user')->latest()->paginate(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not diving further into setting up an eloquent relationship. I hope you have correctly set it up.

Let's focus on the query:

`Post::with('comments', 'user') -> Returns post with comments and who created it. Which is correct but now what you want.`

**Update Your Code**

```
$posts = Post::with(['user', 
    'comments' => function($q) {
        $q->with('user'); //Rename users to user in eloquent model. }
    ])->latest()->paginate(3);
```

Note: not tested. Try it out.

Comment: You can also just `Post::with('comments', 'comments.user', 'user')

Comment: Yes, I know but for simplicity, I prefer to use that way. :) Thanks.